# Getting user's QGIS version using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, versioning

I am trying to write a QGIS plugin, which should work on QGIS 2 and QGIS 3. How can I find out which QGIS version the user is using, so the right imports are made?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In QGis < 3, `qgis.core` has a `QGis` object:

```
>>> from qgis.core import QGis
```

with various formats of the version string:

```
>>> QGis.QGIS_VERSION
u'2.18.5'
>>> QGis.QGIS_VERSION_INT
21805
```

and the release name, fwiw:

```
>>> QGis.QGIS_RELEASE_NAME
u'Las Palmas'
```

In versions 3 and above, this module is renamed `Qgis` for consistency.

There's a bit of a bootstrap problem here, since you can't get the version to figure out if you need to import `Qgis` or `QGis` without knowing. So you probably have to wrap it in a `try` and catch the exception.

```
try:
    from qgis.core import Qgis
except ImportError:
    from qgis.core import QGis as Qgis
```

Answer (score 8):

You can call simply try this inside your plugin

```
from qgis.core import *
print QGis.QGIS_VERSION # will print 2.18.13
```

I dont know if the function is the same in QGIS 3.0  but for 2.18 this worked. The link to the reference can be found [here](https://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQGis.html#a6b0157f79c7ebd7ab16f6ffd21a24b79) in the pyqgis documentation

Answer (score 1):

Just a tiny extension to the @Spacedman's answer.

Since QGIS 3.12, there are several methods ([`version()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a0d007e2054299c72ef8c1ea63dd44c7f), [`versionInt()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#ac3ba88889db18b0cec418e4fea8693ef), and [`releaseName()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a75ae619addade40453a106cd7c4c83b1)) provided via the `Qgis` class.

```py
from qgis.core import Qgis

print(Qgis.version()) #3.28.10-Firenze
print(Qgis.versionInt()) #32810
print(Qgis.releaseName()) #Firenze
```

The same what this code does:

```py
from qgis.core import Qgis

print(Qgis.QGIS_VERSION) #3.28.10-Firenze
print(Qgis.QGIS_VERSION_INT) #32810
print(Qgis.QGIS_RELEASE_NAME) #Firenze
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked well on my system:

Input:

```
from qgis.core import Qgis
print (Qgis.QGIS_VERSION)
```

Output:

```
3.30.0-'s-Hertogenbosch
```

Comment: Dear @CarlosOliveira, it is a pleasure to see new members on the GIS SE. It is a great beginning! :) May I kindly ask you, how does your answer differ from [@Spacedman's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268445/99589)?