# Determine QGIS version in a startup script that PYQGIS_STARTUP points to

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

The environment variable (Win10) PYQGIS_STARTUP points to a python script that is executed before QGIS starts (cp. [Central deployment of startup.py in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319224/central-deployment-of-startup-py-in-qgis/319225#319225)).

Now I need to determine the QGIS version in the python script PYQGIS_STARTUP points to. Of course, this does not work (Answer to [Getting user's QGIS version using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268443/getting-users-qgis-version-using-pyqgis)):

```
try:
    from qgis.core import Qgis
except ImportError:
    from qgis.core import QGis as Qgis

if Qgis.QGIS_VERSION_INT >=30000:
    #do something
else:
    #do something else or nothing
```

resulting in

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'
```

Is there another way to determine QGIS version in such script or am I lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: Determine Python version. Since PyQGIS 3 is allways python 3.X we can use:

```
import sys
if sys.version[0] == '3':
    #do something
elif sys.version[0] == '2':
    #do something else or nothing
```

cp. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/how-do-i-detect-the-python-version-at-runtime